# Can not load xdebug profile by webgrind

Tags: profiler

I have tried to use Webgrind for profiling my application but when I click on Update button it show an error:

```
Could not open D:\Program Files\xampp\tmp/ for reading.
D:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\webgrind\library\Preprocessor.php, line 49
```

I check the permission for folder tmp and sure that it's allow full control for everyone.
The folder D:\Program Files\xampp\tmp has file xdebug_profile.6096, mean the xdebug worked correctly (I also tested xdebug by using Netbeans with xdebug and it works normally).

My system:

Windows Vista

XAMPP 1.7.3

Webgrind 1.02

Anyone have experience of this? Please help me!

Comment: Have you tried [random-pausing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024)?

Comment: Sorry but it's seem too complicated and I don't know about Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I have it Thang.

Try adding an extra directory directive to your vhost.
This should allow the server to access folders outside of it's directory.

I've added my vhost I use for my localhost on my windows machine.

```
#template vhost container

NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>

    DocumentRoot C:\www
    ServerName localhost
    CustomLog logs/localhost-transfer.log combined
    ErrorLog logs/localhost-error.log

    # Non configurable settings

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

    <Directory C:\www>
        Options Indexes
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "C:/xampp/tmp">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```